# Reading datatable with varying columns into an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I want to read a datatable which consists of varying columns per row into an array.

My sample data looks like this

```
1 0.000 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.098   0.000   
1 0.000 0.051   0.851   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000           
1 0.000 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.266   0.203   0.000   
1 0.011 0.210   0.311   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   
1 0.000 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.009   0.007   0.497       
1 0.004 0.023   0.063   0.140   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   
1 0.027 0.010   0.130   0.192   0.156   0.082   0.068
```

I managed to put it into an array as shown below:

```
public static double[][] dataTableToMatrix(DataTable dt)
    {
       double[][] data = new double[dt.Rows.Count][];

        for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count;x++)
        {
            data[x] = new double[dt.Columns.Count];

            for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
            {
                if ((dt.Rows[x][y]) != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    data[x][y] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[x][y]);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
        return data;

    }
```

I tried the code above but the resulting array has always the highest column count along with zeroes whenever there is a shorter column. I want to read it until the last value in each row then jump to the next row. Any solutions to this issue?

Comment: Is even possible to create a table with different row lengths? Aren't you sure you are misunderstanding row length vs a value being null?

Comment: DataTables do not support variable length rows.  The columns are defined at the schema level, much like a database table.  It's likely that these blanks are null values, which you are indeed handling in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right your problem this would do what you want (instead of pre-allocating the sub arrays just use Lists and then convert them to arrays):

```
public static double[][] dataTableToMatrix(DataTable dt)
{
   double[][] data = new double[dt.Rows.Count][];

    for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count;x++)
    {
        List<double> items = new List<double>();

        for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[x][y] != DBNull.Value)
                items.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[x][y]));
            else
                break;
        }

        data[x] = items.ToArray();

    } 

    return data;

}
```

Comment: Amazing! this worked perfectly fine! Could you briefly explain why did it work with Lists ?

Comment: Simple, your arrays where being created with the table's row size, a table has the same column count on each row, so all your arrays would be always of the size of the table column count. The List is a variable size collection, the code adds elements until it finds a null value on a column and then converts the List with the exact elements to an array.

Comment: As I was pointing on the comment at your question, you are misinterpreting having a null value as if the column doesn't exists on the row, and that's totally wrong, the column exists always on each row, but it may have a null value, that's completely different to not existing.

Comment: Finally, if the answer was helpful mark it as the solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static double[][] dataTableToMatrix(DataTable dt)
{
   double[][] data = new double[dt.Rows.Count][];

    for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count;x++)
    {
        var countOfNonNullValuesInRow = dt.Rows[x].ItemArray.Count(a => a != DBNull.Value);
        data[x] = new double[countOfNonNullValuesInRow];

        for (int y = 0; y < countOfNonNullValuesInRow; y++)
        {
            data[x][y] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[x][y]);
        }
    } 
    return data;
}
```